# Is the function, $f(z)=iz\bar{z}$ analytic?

Tags: complex-analysis

> Question: Is the function, $f(z)=iz\bar{z}$ analytic?

My approach: We know that for any $z\in\mathbb{C}$, $z\bar{z}=|z|^2.$ Thus $f(z)=i|z|^2, \forall z.$ Now let $z=x+iy\implies f(z)=f(x+iy)=i(x^2+y^2).$ Thus we have $u(x,y)=0$ and $v(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.

Now observe that both $u$ and $v$ are continuous functions in $x$ and $y$, $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$

Now $$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=0, \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}=0,\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}=2x,\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}=2y, \forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$$

Thus the functions $\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}},\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}},\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}},\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}$ are continuous $\forall x,y\in\mathbb{R}.$

Now we move forward to analyze if the Cauchy-Riemann conditions are satisfied or not.

Observe that since $$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=0 \text{ and } \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}=2y, \text{ therefore } \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}}=\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{y}}\iff 2y=0\iff y=0.$$

Again since, $$\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}=0 \text{ and } -\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}=-2x, \text{ therefore } \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{y}}=-\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}\iff -2x=0\iff x=0.$$

Thus the Cauchy-Riemann conditions are satisfied only at the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$, i.e., at the point $z=0$.

Thus we can conclude that $f$ is analytic only at the point $z=0$.

I have read in the book "Advanced Engineering Mathematics" by Erwin Kreyszig that:

> A function $f(z)$ is said to be analytic at a point $z=z_0$ in a domain $D$ if $f(z)$ is analytic in a neighborhood of $z_0$.

But, here we see that $f(z)$ is analytic only at the point $z=0$, and not in any $\delta$ neighborhood of $z=0$. So, can we still conclude that $f(z)$ is analytic at the point $z=0$? And, obviously $f(z)$ is not a analytic function, since it is not differentiable at every point in some domain.

Comment: No, as the definition says, a function cannot be analytic at a single point, though it can be differentiable at a single point.

Comment: $f(z)$ is complex differentiable at $z=0$, but since it is not differentiable on any open set containing the origin, it is not analytic anywhere

Comment: That $z\bar z$ is a red herring: take any real-valued function instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the Cauchy-Riemann equations were satisfied in an open set $D$, you could conclude that your function was analytic in $D$.  But here the C-R equations are only satisfied at one point.  That does **not** say your function is analytic at that point, it says your function is not analytic at all, because to be analytic at a point (according to the definition) it must be analytic in a neighbourhood of the point.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy-Riemann only tells you when $f$ is complex differentiable at $0$, not holomorphic at $0$.